# What does librosa.load return?

Tags: audio, python, dsp-core

I'm new to signal processing and I'm working with librosa library quite a bit.

1. I would like to know what is the information that is returned by librosa.load function when I read a audio(.wav) file using it. Is it the instantaneous sound pressure in pa? or the just the instantaneous amplitude of the sound signal with no unit?
2. How can I use this information to calculate the SPL(no-weigting) of the signal ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it the instantaneous sound pressure in pa?

How would a piece of software know about sound pressure? What it gets is the digitized voltage from a microphone, with zero information about the physical sensitivity of that microphone.

> or the just the instantaneous amplitude of the sound signal with no unit?

Exactly! :)

> How can I use this information to calculate the SPL(no-weigting) of the signal?

Calibrate your recording setup with a sound source of known power. That's the only way short of buying an expensive calibrated measurement microphone, amplifier, digitizer. But then, there will be little need for librosa.

Comment: Does this instantaneous amplitude represent the change in atmospheric pressure created by the sound source(s) while recording?

Comment: it's **proportional** to the instantaneous pressure.

Comment: So, can the instantaneous pressure be used with the reference atmospheric pressure(20e-6) to calculate the relevant SPL?

Comment: no. constant pressure doesn't contribute to SPL.

Comment: Doesn't the instantaneous pressure keep varying(possibly) sample-to-sample? Why do you say this is constant pressure then?

Comment: your reference atmospheric pressure is constant. Your microphone doesn't "see" it.

Comment: Of course the mic doesn’t know it. I was talking about calculating the SPL using a programming language.